# How to start JVM via JPype on Linux?

Tags: python-3.x, aspose, aspose-cells, jpype

I use `Aspose.Cells` for Python via Java on Linux. I try to start the `JVM`, but it gives me an error because it looks like it can't find and enable it.

> File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jpype/imports.py", line 155, in find_spec
> raise ImportError("Attempt to create Java package '%s' without jvm" % name)
> ImportError: Attempt to create Java package 'com' without jvm

I tried adding an `ENV` for it to find it and also writing the path in the constructor, but nothing helps.

```python
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
jpype.startJVM()
```

or

```python
jpype.startJVM("/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server/libjvm.so")
```

What is the correct path to create and initialize `JVM`?

Comment: Please see the document (https://docs.aspose.com/cells/python-java/getting-started/) for your reference. If you still find the issue, share the sample code that you are using with Aspose.Cells for Python via Java.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: @AmjadSahi I wrote `os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["PATH"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin"
jpype.startJVM()` , but it doesn`t help. Same error.

Comment: The error message produced by `jpype.startJVM()` would be interesting in this case. The exception message posted is just saying, that you tried to inspect a Java package without having an JVM instance.